# Why Tailwind some classes don't work in React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to use Tailwind to style my app in React but some classes are not working, how can I fix it? And what would affect it?

```
function NavBar({ title }) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar mb-12 shadow-lg bg-neutral text-neutral-content">
      <div className="container mx-auto">
        <div className="flex-none px-2 mx-2">
          <AiFillGithub />
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

but on web page nothing changed.

Comment: Hello. Do you have maybe some minimal reproducible code sample for it? Like codesandbox or snippet?

Comment: Hi! I am doing udemy course and follow it, and I follow the tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

I sorted out the problem, in file tailwind.config.js I had:

```
content:["./src/**/*.{html,js}", "./components/**/*.{html,js}"]
```

and I should change for:

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"]
```

I posted my solution just in case if someone will face the same problem

Comment: This worked for me. I sometimes use .jsx instead of .js so I had to make sure the file was .js for it to work

Comment: You save my life thank you for adding this answer. I was finding solution for hours.